# Unable To use closets and nexall method in javascript

Tags: jquery

```
$(".w-input").blur(function(event) {
  allInOne(event);
})

function allInOne(event) {
  var name = event.target.name
  $(name).nextAll(".errortext").css("display", "block");
  console.log(name);
}
```

i have error in executing nextall and closest function

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it a function not found or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just remove name from `event.target.name` i.e `event.target` which will give you target Node.

```js
$(".w-input").blur(function (event) {
    allInOne(event);
})  
function allInOne(event){ 
    var name = event.target
    $(name).nextAll(".errortext").removeClass("hide");
    $(name).nextAll(".errortext").css("display", "block");
    console.log(name);
}
```

```css
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="w-input">
<p class="hide errortext">Hello Error block</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much You save My time

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following because `event.target.name` will only get you a string which is not a valid selector.

```
function allInOne(event) {
  var obj = event.target;
  $(obj).nextAll(".errortext").css("display", "block");
  console.log(obj.name);
}
```